# Pre-1993 comic in which Wolverine's claws were turned to rubber?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, x-men, wolverine

I remember many years ago reading a comic in which a one-appearance (or at any rate, obscure) character with transmutation powers turns Wolverine's claws to wobbly rubber. Wolverine, who had been in middle of rashly lashing out with a stab, hears an unexpected "B-BOING!" as his claws harmlessly bounce off the target of his rage, and I think maybe even says, stunned, "'B-boing'?!?" ⎩O<sub>⌓</sub>o⎭

The transmuter character later restores them to adamantium. (I think he wasn't a villain, just some decent guy who had been blackmailed by an actual villain that if he didn't help, someone close to him would be harmed, or something like that.)

This is arguably in contradiction to the later event in *X-Men* #25 in 1993 (during the "Fatal Attractions" storyline) when Magneto ripped out the adamantium, which led to the reveal they actually had had natural bone in them all along.

The following could be wrong, but I vaguely recall that it might have been in a comic in which Wolverine didn't usually appear, like *Excalibur*. This would have had to have been in an early '90s comic or earlier (i.e. before "Fatal Attractions").

Comment: Thanos turns his whole skeleton to rubber in _Infinity Gauntlet_ but I don’t think he restores it later on. Could that be what you’re thinking if?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot No, unless I somehow wholly dreamt this thing up at some point (I don't think that's the case), I'm pretty sure it was some lesser character, and just Wolverine's claws.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is the comic you're referring to; [**Excalibur Vol 1 #58**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Excalibur_Vol_1_58). Wolverine has his claws turned (temporarily) into rubber by [Alchemy](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Jones_(Earth-616)) at the urging of a troll.

[image]

Answer (score 108):

*Excalibur* #58 (1992) fits the bill, your villain being Alchemy.

From [ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/excalibur-58-troll-call/4000-36512/):

> Trouble on both sides! With both the Crazy Gang and the trolls that kidnapped Alchemy on the loose, can even the combined strength of Excalibur and the X-Men come out on top?

[image: Wolverine's rubber claws]

As revealed in the previous issue, Alchemy was in with the trolls who used his mother as leverage for him to transmute back their fellow trolls.

[image: Alchemy is not given a choice]

---

Found with the Google query `wolverine claws rubber site:marvel.fandom.com`.

Comment: Hey, at least your answer contains the aforementioned scene that was quoted in the question and has more than twice the upvotes too.